# Find the equation of the side of the triangle given its bisectors

Tags: geometry

I need help solving the following problem:

You are given a triangle $ABC$ with

- One of the points is $A(1,2)$
- One of its angle bisectors equation is $x+2= 0$
- One of its angle bisectors equation is $y= x+5$

What's the equation for the side $BC$?

Comment: Angle bisectors or perpendicular bisectors? What do you mean by "it's bisectors"?

Comment: @peterwhy I meant angle bisectors. Also "it's bisectors" was just a typo. I edited them, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: Find the Symmetrical Points of A over the two given bisectors.

It should result in the line: $\epsilon_{BC}: y = 2x + 12$